# Android exoplayer, display current time on the scrubber as you scroll

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, exoplayer-media-item

I've been looking at [`TimeBar`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/TimeBar.html) and [`DefaultTimeBar`](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/DefaultTimeBar.html) to try and figure out how to add the current timestamp as you scroll through the video.

Example of what I mean (from the GoPro app):

[image]

I am trying to edit the code from [codelab-exoplayer-intro repo](https://github.com/android/codelab-exoplayer-intro/tree/main), you can see the current timestamp in the bottom left corner, but I'd like to be similar to what the GoPro app is doing.

[image]

I'm not sure what the slider bar is called and how to approach this problem.